# Gmail rejects mails via ipv6 as Spam

Tags: dns, gmail, ipv6

Sometimes when I send from my server, I get the following response from Gmail (IP masked by me)

```
: host aspmx.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c00::1a]
said: 550-5.7.1 [2a01:**:**:**::2      12] Our system has detected that
this 550-5.7.1 message is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of
spam sent 550-5.7.1 to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please visit
550-5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131
for 550 5.7.1 more information. hm5si113822760wjb.117 - gsmtp (in reply to
end of DATA command)
```

Some people recommended to disable IPv6 for Gmail. But google seems to miss an IPv6 PTR entry in the DNS. I found some help on this, but all this stuff is a bit above my head.

To my understanding I just have to create a PTR record for instance with the help of [this](http://rdns6.com/hostRecord) tool and add that to my DNS record.

Is it that simple?

*edit* [Some](https://yeri.be/gmail-google-apps-ipv6) [links](http://tanguy.ortolo.eu/blog/article109/google-ipv6-smtp-restrictions) to the Problem.

Comment: If you want a reverse DNS record, you’ll have to ask your server provider to generate it. My server has been running IPv6 for years now and I never had any problems with rejected mails.

Comment: The reason Google believes its spam has nothing to do with it being IPv6 but everything to do with the DNS record not existing.  Furthermore the information you quoted indicates that Google itself is using a IPv6 address.

Comment: @DanielB I have control over the DNS entry myself. I just want to know if the process is correct and that simple (because I've read many complicated things about this problem).

Comment: No, you don’t. Reverse DNS zones are controlled by the IP owners. Which is not you, but your provider. The only exception is if you have the reverse zone delegated.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test/ This helped me fixing gmail problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PTR generator tool you linked to seems to generate the correct information for an ipv6 PTR record. I would add that, and probably an SPF record if you do not have one already. That should improve your reputation and increase the likelihood of delivery to Gmail and other mail hosts. As others mentioned, it is not to do with ipv6 at all.

There is an SPF generator, similar to the PTR one at http://www.spfwizard.net/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also added an SPF record and I think it considerably increased my score.

Comment: Gmail has a specific guidelines for IPv6: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126 (The linked was shared on this answer: http://serverfault.com/a/538060/130225)